# Separate blocks of texts using regular expressions - Python

Tags: python, parsing, tuples

I have the following output from the Stanford Parser:

```
nicaragua president ends visit to finland .

nn(ends-3, nicaragua-1)
nn(ends-3, president-2)
nsubj(visit-4, ends-3)
xsubj(finland-6, ends-3)
root(ROOT-0, visit-4)
aux(finland-6, to-5)
xcomp(visit-4, finland-6)

guatemala president ends visit to tropos .

nn(ends-3, guatemala-1)
nn(ends-3, president-2)
nsubj(visit-4, ends-3)
xsubj(finland-6, ends-3)
root(ROOT-0, visit-4)
aux(tropos-6, to-5)
xcomp(visit-4, tropos-6)

[...]
```

I have to segment this output so to get to tuples contaning the sentence and a list of all dependencies (as in `(sentence,[list of dependencies])` for each of the sentences. Can someone please suggest me a way to do this in Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, although its probably overkill for the structure you're parsing.  It should be relatively easy to extend if you need to parse the dependencies as well.  I haven't run this yet, or even checked the syntax so don't kill me if it doesn't work right away.

```
READ_SENT = 0
PRE_DEPS = 1
DEPS = 2
POST_DEPS = 3
def parse_output(input):
    state = READ_SENT
    results = []
    sent = None
    deps = []
    for line in input.splitlines():
        if state == READ_SENT:
            sent = line
            state = PRE_DEPS
        elif state == PRE_DEPS:
             if line:
                 raise Exception('invalid format')
             else:
                 state = DEPS
         elif state == DEPS:
             if line:
                 deps.append(line)
             else:
                 state = POST_DEPS
         elif state == POST_DEPS:
             if line:
                 raise Exception('invalid format')
             else:
                 results.append((sent, deps))
                 sent = None
                 deps = []
                 state = READ_SENT
    return results
```